# C++ CMAKE Predicate no such file

Tags: c++, qt, boost, cmake

First of all, the error log:

```
-- Boost version: 1.59.0
-- Success!
-- Could NOT find Freetype (missing:  FREETYPE_LIBRARY) (found version "2.6.3")
-- LOADING OS --Windows--
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Gianluca/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/mcdu-57fe38f9/57fe38f9/Debug
[  1%] Automatic moc for target untitled
[  1%] Built target untitled_automoc
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.obj
[  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/mainwindow.cpp.obj
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/gldisplay.cpp.obj
[  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/svg/svg.cpp.obj
[  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/svg/svgfont.cpp.obj
[  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/svg/svgstring.cpp.obj
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/ht1000scriptmanager.cpp.obj
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/ht1000widgetfactory.cpp.obj
CMakeFiles\untitled.dir\build.make:149: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/svg/svg.cpp.obj' failed
In file included from C:\Work\PolitecProductions\mcdu\svg\svg.cpp:1:0:
C:\Work\PolitecProductions\mcdu\svg\svg.h:14:48: fatal error: boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
                                                ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from C:\Work\PolitecProductions\mcdu\svg\svgstring.cpp:3:0:
C:\Work\PolitecProductions\mcdu\svg\./svg.h:14:48: fatal error: boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
                                                ^
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/svg/svg.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from C:\Work\PolitecProductions\mcdu\svg\svgfont.cpp:2:0:
C:\Work\PolitecProductions\mcdu\svg\./svg.h:14:48: fatal error: boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
                                                ^
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles\untitled.dir\build.make:199: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/svg/svgstring.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/svg/svgstring.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\untitled.dir\build.make:174: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/svg/svgfont.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/svg/svgfont.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\untitled.dir\build.make:249: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/ht1000widgetfactory.cpp.obj' failed
In file included from C:\Work\PolitecProductions\mcdu\ht1000widgetfactory.cpp:1:0:
C:\Work\PolitecProductions\mcdu\./ht1000widgetfactory.h:5:25: fatal error: QScriptEngine: No such file or directory
 #include <QScriptEngine>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
```

more http://pastebin.com/72ySYdVd

This is my actual CMakeLists

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(mcdu)


#### Boost Check Version
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Success!")
endif()
#### Qt5
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Script REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(FREETYPE)
set(QT_LIBRARIES Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core Qt5::OpenGL Qt5::Core Qt5::Script)


set( CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON )  
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_COVERAGE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage ")
add_definitions("-std=c++11")


# Find includes in corresponding build directories
include_directories(
        ${BOOST}
        ${FREETYPE}
        ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        -lopengl32 -lglu32 -luser32
)

if (WIN32)
    message(STATUS "LOADING OS --Windows--")
    include_directories(
    ${BOOST}/lib32-msvc-14.0 -libboost_timer-vc140-mt-gd-1_59 -libboost_log-vc140-mt-gd-1_59 -libboost_log_setup-vc140-mt-gd-1_59
    ${FREETYPE}/objs/vc2010/Win32/ -lfreetype263d
    )
endif ()


#Source Files
set(SOURCE_FILES
        src files. Cut to be short

#Header Files
set(HEADER_FILES
        header files. Cut to be short
        )

#Add Forms
QT5_WRAP_UI(FORM_FILES
        .ui files
        )


add_executable(untitled ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES} ${FORM_FILES})
```

more http://pastebin.com/uGf3SHUn

So under svg.h the include is as it follows:
`#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>`

I've MSVC2015 and BOOST + FREETYPE env. variables are added to the system AND Clion. If I build that from QT I only get predicate.hpp error.

Here is the QT PRO file

```
QT += core gui script opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = mcdu
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += WIN
DEFINES += OGLFT_NO_SOLID
DEFINES += OGLFT_NO_QT
DEFINES += TEST

INCLUDEPATH += $$(BOOST)
INCLUDEPATH += $$(FREETYPE)/include
INCLUDEPATH += status
INCLUDEPATH += systems
INCLUDEPATH += svg
INCLUDEPATH += displays

CONFIG += debug

win32 {
    DEFINES += WINDOWS
    LIBS += -lopengl32 -lglu32 -luser32
    LIBS += -L$$(BOOST)/lib32-msvc-14.0 -libboost_timer-vc140-mt-gd-1_59 -libboost_log-vc140-mt-gd-1_59 -libboost_log_setup-vc140-mt-gd-1_59
    LIBS += -L$$(FREETYPE)/objs/vc2010/Win32/ -lfreetype263d
}

linux {
    message("Build for Linux")
    DEFINES += LINUX
    DEFINES += BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK
    LIBS += -lGLU
    LIBS += -lfreetype
    LIBS += -L/home/RINF/rogosz/source/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib -lboost_timer -lboost_log -lboost_log_setup -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem
}

SOURCES += src files: cut to be short

HEADERS  += header files. cut to be short

FORMS    += form files. cut to be short
```

Comment: Please don't just include links.  Put the error log, the CMakeLists and the QT PRO file actually in your question.

Comment: Downvoted as the question is unclear, poorly presented (no attempt to reduce the problem / approaching a [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example), and shows little research effort (apparently the OP has not consulted the CMake documentation). Answered nevertheless.

Comment: @DevSolar: Why are you answering such questions? Downvoting and posting your comment from your answer should be enough.

Comment: @user1234567: Because by the time I realize how "broken" a question is, I have alreasy spotted a number of issues. Answering them means 1) the OP does not continue thinking SO is unhelpful or CMake is broken; 2) the OP has a chance to flag an answer "correct", closing the question; 3) the OP has a reason to accept my comment as informed and constructive instead of condescending. All in all, call it "decency".

Answer (score 0):

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

# ...

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
include_directories(
        ${BOOST}
        ${FREETYPE}
        ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        -lopengl32 -lglu32 -luser32
)
```

The variable set by the `find_package( Boost ... )`, containing the path to the Boost header files, is named `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS`, not `BOOST`.

And unless FREETYPE is breaking the pattern, that should be `FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS` as well.

And what are the linker directives (`-lopengl32 -lglu32 -luser32`) doing in there?

```
if (WIN32)
    message(STATUS "LOADING OS --Windows--")
    include_directories(
    ${BOOST}/lib32-msvc-14.0 -libboost_timer-vc140-mt-gd-1_59 -libboost_log-vc140-mt-gd-1_59 -libboost_log_setup-vc140-mt-gd-1_59
    ${FREETYPE}/objs/vc2010/Win32/ -lfreetype263d
    )
endif ()
```

I am *quite* confused. What is this even meant to achieve? You use the command `include_directories()`, but it looks as if you are trying to give linker instructions here? Adding link dependencies is done via `target_link_libraries()`...

And even if you would be using the correct command, you would not give linker instructions (`-lfreetype263d`), but list link targets, preferably those provided by the various `find_package()` calls, i.e. `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` (not `${BOOST}`), and `${FREETYPE_LIBRARIES}` (not `${FREETYPE}`).

Further:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_COVERAGE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage ")
add_definitions("-std=c++11")
```

These are compiler-specific options that won't float your boat if you are working with Visual Studio. Use `if ( MSVC )` and `if ( CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC )` to check what compiler you are working with.

Comment: @Stealth: No offense intended, but it looks as if you are going trial-and-error here, without really knowing what you are doing. You have problems all over the place, and I have been looking *only* at your `CMakeLists.txt` so far (as that is what you tagged the question with)... I suggest you start with something more simple, and take small steps, with the CMake docs at hand until you feel comfortable with it.